# In Eclipse, how can I view which ui class is active?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, debugging

I know that there is a feature in Eclipse that shows the class name of the active element of the eclipse interface (for example, the class of the element selected with mouse). It is used to debug client plugin extensions, but I don't remember how to call it..

How can I get this feature? Which key combination I can use?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the Plug-in Spy plug-in. Press <kbd>Alt+Shift+F1</kbd> to see to details about the current selection. <kbd>Alt+Shift+F2</kbd> lets to find out information about menu items.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, Michele.